# pass input values from component.html to compoenent.ts

Tags: javascript, angular

I am very new to angular ,I am trying to add product to my cart on button click
the products are generated dynamically 
this is my component.html

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#" class="card clickable">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <img src="">
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                        <h5>product1</h5>
                        <h5>aweeee112ddddd</h5>
                        <h5>1</h5>
                        <input type="hidden" name=""  value="aweeee112ddddd" id="" #productid>
                    <p class="card-text">

                        <button class="btn btn-outline" (click)="addtocart(this.productid)">Addtocart</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#" class="card clickable">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <img src="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <p class="card-text">
                                <input type="hidden" name=""  value="vvvv112ddddd" id="" #productid>
 <input type="hidden" name=""  value="product1" id="" #productname>
                            <button class="btn btn-outline" (click)="addtocart(this.productid)">Addtocart</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="#" class="card clickable">
                        <div class="card-img">
                            <img src="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
<input type="hidden" name=""  value="vppp112ddddd" id="" #productid>
 <input type="hidden" name=""  value="product2" id="" #productname>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline" (click)="addtocart()">Addtocart</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my component.ts

```
export class Products  {

    addtocart(item1,item2,item3){
        alert(item.value);
        //alert("item added");
         this.cartservice.additems(item1,item2,item3);
        return false;
    }
    constructor(public cartservice:CartService){

    }}
```

I want to pass my hidden fields value to component.ts ,the products will be displayed dynamically ,from database any help will be really appreciated

Comment: use [(ngModel)] directive https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use ngModel, IMO it is better to use form controls. You'll get all power of the rxjs (via valueChanges), at least.
To perform that, you should:

1. Import `ReactiveFormsModule` to your host module
2. Add a `formCotrol` directive to `input` - e.g.

   Define form control in the component - `public myControl = new FormControl()`

Then work with it as [described in docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)